# Get default terminal application on linux system using Java

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I am looking for a way to find out which one of these `xterm, konsole, aterm, gnome-terminal` terminal applications are present on Linux distro or a default one at runtime within a java program.

It is required to execute certain commands from my java program and so need to know which terminal to use or at least if it is present and can be used.

xterm can be used by default but would be good to know if there is something more advanced available to use. Even there is no guarantee if xterm is installed either.

Comment: What's the link? Why do you need a terminal emulator to execute commands from a Java application?

Comment: I need to execute another jar tool, to perform some task.
BTW java -jar does not open java console for console tool.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. You don't need a terminal emulator to programatically execute other programs. Further, if you are calling other Java programs then simply load them with a `ClassLoader` and just call the methods.

Comment: The whole story is to be able to see the terminal for the output. I have to start the jar tool from within another jar tool., The parent jar tool closes after starting the child jar tool. I have the solution to use xterm but however, I needed to know if there is anything generic too detect terminal. If I need it or not, it would be great to know if it can be done in Java.

Comment: Start the process or run the command. Open a `JFrame`. Fill with output. What you're trying to do sounds like a hack.

Comment: Yes, kind of a hack. Don't really know how to achieve that. Nevermind, will try using Jframe as well. The child Jar tool only does its task. If everything's okay, it closes. If any errors, it holds the window and waits for the user to enter, so the user can read it.

In addition, can't really rely on UI elements, since this tool could be used on terminal based remote vm. I still have to learn about that on the other hand. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full portability and a "native terminal emulator", you will have to code something that picks the "right" terminal emulator yourself. There are two commands that do a bit of choosing themselves:

- On Debian based Distro's you can use `x-terminal-emulator -e <cmd>`, however this does not work on e.g. Centos.
- FreeDesktop has `xdg-terminal` ([code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-terminal.in)) as part of the `xdg-utils` package, however the script seems not to be distributed at all.

Since neither of these is guaranteed to be present, you will still have to test for availability and use xterm etc. as fall-back.